# How to append additional text found in a duplicate entry to the original text

Tags: linux, shell, join

I have two files:

File#1:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
```

File#2:

```
aaa,a,a
abc,a,b
bbb,b,b
ccc,c,c
def,g,h
ddd,d,d
eee,e,e
fff,f,f
ggg,g,g
```

How do I append the data (ex. ",a,a") from file #2 to file #1 only in the case a duplicate is found and without adding additional data (ex. ggg,g,g)?

Result of file #1 should be:

```
aaa,a,a
bbb,b,b
ccc,c,c
ddd,d,d
eee,e,e
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), if you run

```
mlr --csv -N join -j 1 -f input01 then unsparsify input02
```

you will have

```
aaa,a,a
bbb,b,b
ccc,c,c
ddd,d,d
eee,e,e
```